# Help me in understanding a flashing LED circuit

Tags: led, transistors, batteries, capacitor, resistors

Now we have two circuits one with single npn lets take it as first circuit and another circuit with one npn and one pnp lets take it as second circuit.
when i tried out both the circuits. the first circuit has no output in the sense the capacitor does not discharges.
coming to second circuit the output is the led blink so it means the capacitor discharges
can anyone explain how the capacitor discharges in second circuit and why it does not discharges in the first circuit?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The capacitor is installed backwards-maybe.

Comment: How do you think the circuit works?

Comment: @Sparky256 , no the capacitor is the right way, it sees at-most 0.6V reverse bias.

Comment: Easily improved design by moving the LED as part of the 22 Ohm resistor load. Might even remove the 1k resistor then.

Comment: Please replace the first image (a wiring diagram) with a schematic. If it's Fritzing then it should be able to create one for you or you can use the built-in schematic tool - there's a button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: Capacitor discharge path is c1-Q1-R1-Q2-Gnd-Battery-R1...Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

I'll get you started. With any circuit analysis it helps to start from a known state, so let's assume  that you've just turned the circuit on and C1 is fully discharged so we can consider it to be a short circuit. Let's also assume that the battery is giving out 6 volts.

Then R1 and R2 form a potential divider, and the voltage across R1 is

6*R1/(R1+R2) = 132uV

So with a Vbe as low as that, Q1 is turned off, no current flows through R3 and Q2 is also turned off; the LED is not lit.

The current flowing through R1 and R2 now starts charging C1. After a certain length of time, the voltage across C1 and R1 becomes high enough to turn on Q1 and current begins to flow through R3.

Let's see if you can take it from there.

Comment: I think capacitor is connected in the wrong direction. I have tried simulation but only works when a capacitor is in opposite direction to the position of itself in this diagram.

Comment: Try using a non-polarised capacitor in the simulation.

Comment: thank you. i have read capacitor will discharge whenever power source turned off. but here power source is always on and hence i am confused how capacitor discharge?

Comment: If the power source is removed it's going to stop flashing! Think about what happens when Q1 turns on, in particular to the junction of R1 and C1.

Answer (score 0):

when Q2 (BC547) turns on current flows through the emitter-base junction of Q1 (BC557) through the capacitor and into Q2

When Q2 is off the capacitor charges through the two resistors.